# Voglio che sarà/vorrò che sarà

Tags: verbs, grammar

1. Voglio che sarà perfetta per quando ritornerò
2. Un giorno forse vorrò che verrai anche tu.

È scorretto usare i tempi verbali futuri come il futuro anteriore e futuro semplice?

Answer (score 3):

Lo stimato linguista e filologo prof. Luca Serianni, come riportato in un commento da @DaG, scrisse nel suo famoso e citatissimo paragrafo XIV.53 quanto segue:

[image]

D'altro canto, l'altrettanto stimato Giovanni Battista Moretti, le cui opere vengono spesso citate a riferimento dallo stesso Serianni, scrive in "Per una didattica dell'italiano" CDU 805.0-56:801.25 (in particolare si notino gli esempi in cui l'oggettiva indica azione posteriore rispetto alla reggente):

[image]

Punto a):
[image]

Punto e):
[image]

Nota 6:
[image]

In relazione alle frasi "voglio che sarà" e "vorrò che sarà", e in generale all'uso dell'indicativo futuro nelle subordinate rette dal verbo "volere", oltre alla sensazione comunque soggettiva di rifiuto di tale costruzione, anche una ricerca nel corpus di Ngram genera invariabilmente zero risultati.

In una discussione su [achyra.org](https://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6270&p=60402&hilit=qualunque%20verbo%20o%20qualunque%20costrutto%20che%20richieda%20il%20congiuntivo%20pu%C3%B2#p60402) qualcuno dice di aver già fatto notare al prof. Serianni la necessità di "sfumare" la sua affermazione.

In base a quanto detto, sembrerebbe pertanto applicabile al famoso XIV.53 l'epigrafe scelta dallo stesso Serianni nel suo "Prima lezione di grammatica":

> Non può mai darsi una regola tanto vergine che da qualche eccettione non sia deflorata
> Loreto Mattei (1695)

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, i tempi verbali futuri nelle tue frasi vanno utilizzati nel seguente modo:

1. Voglio che sia perfetta al mio ritorno.
2. Un giorno forse vorrò che venga anche tu.

In entrambi i casi è necessario inserire un congiuntivo. Mentre nella prima "voglio che sarà" è scorretto, nella seconda non era scorretta la parte al futuro in sé, bensì il periodo successivo che ne esprimeva meglio il significato.

Come @DaG ha giustamente fatto notare, in realtà “Voglio che sarà” non si può definire propriamente scorretto, nonostante probabilmente oggi non sentirai mai nessuno dirlo (e sopravvivere per raccontarlo).

> *Qualunque verbo o qualunque costrutto che richieda il congiuntivo può costruirsi con l'indicativo futuro ... quando l'oggettiva indica azione posteriore rispetto alla reggente*

Comment: Ho ripensato a questa domanda e devo fare una piccola osservazione. “Voglio che sarà” non si può definire veramente scorretto. Come dice Serianni nel suo _Italiano_ (XIV.53), “qualunque verbo o qualunque costrutto che richieda il congiuntivo può costruirsi con l'indicativo futuro ... quando l'oggettiva indica azione posteriore rispetto alla reggente” e lo esemplifica con una frase dal cap. XXXIV dei _Promessi Sposi_: “Anche voi – riprese Renzo – credo che potrete farmi un piacere”. Poi, ritengo anch'io che in questo specifico caso suona meglio il congiuntivo.

Comment: @DaG Verissimo, e sicuramente ne sai più di me in materia. Non ne sono sicuro, ma credo che purtroppo possa risultare molto complesso per un parlatore non madre lingua distinguere i casi in cui l'italiano suona meglio rispetto a quelli dove suona peggio, qualità che immagino si ottenga solo tramite l'esperienza. Si tratta di un aspetto molto interessante a cui non avevo mai pensato, ho corretto la mia risposta :)